# Class imbalance for image data

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am new to Deep learning. I am currently working with video data. I extracted from it the image data. However, I am aware about the class imbalance of the data meaning class 0 has more samples than class 1. How is it possible to spot that as I still have not done my classification to know whether class 0 will have more samples or not. Could kindly let me know if this is the first step in processing my images. Can you have a manual count of the class by looking to the videos and then split them equally but I assume there is a much efficient and automated way. Any libraries that can help would be so much appreciated. Thank you for your help.

I tried to look up some concepts such as downsampling and random sampling.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You just look at the distribution of the labels, because your data has labels, right?